# Выделить область на QGraphicsScene

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsview

Хотел сделать выделение области, например, как на рабочем столе. Добавляем прямоугольник при повторном действии старый удаляется новый прорисовается. Или можно использовать QRubberband для этих целей?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Qscene(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
       super(Qscene, self).__init__(parent)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super(Qscene, self).mousePressEvent(event)

        self.xRect = event.scenePos().x()
        self.yRect = event.scenePos().y()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        super(Qscene, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)
        QGraphicsScene.addRect(self,self.xRect,self.yRect,self.endX- 
        self.xRect,self.endY-self.yRect)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        super(Qscene, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)
        self.endX = event.scenePos().x()
        self.endY = event.scenePos().y()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QWidget()
    scene = Qscene()
    view = QGraphicsView()
    view.setScene(scene)

    hbox = QGridLayout()
    hbox.addWidget(view)

    window.setLayout(hbox)
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

QGraphicsScene.clear()  - удаляет все предметы со сцены

Попробуйте:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Qscene(QGraphicsScene):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Qscene, self).__init__(parent)



    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super(Qscene, self).mousePressEvent(event)

        self.xRect = event.scenePos().x()
        self.yRect = event.scenePos().y()


    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        super(Qscene, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)

        QGraphicsScene.clear(self)                        # +++

        QGraphicsScene.addRect(self,self.xRect,self.yRect,self.endX- 
        self.xRect,self.endY-self.yRect)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        super(Qscene, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)
        self.endX = event.scenePos().x()
        self.endY = event.scenePos().y()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QWidget()
    scene = Qscene()
    view = QGraphicsView()
    view.setScene(scene)

    hbox = QGridLayout()
    hbox.addWidget(view)

    window.setLayout(hbox)
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

В с++ это так будет, в Питоне точно так же должен метод называться. Делает из коробки то, что вам нужно

```
setDragMode(RubberBandDrag);
```